# Synchronization between 4 VideoView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-videoview

I have 4 `VideoView`s in my activity, and I want that they all start at the same time. I did it in an `AsyncTask` and it work fine, but sometimes one of the `VideoView` is getting delayed and then the Synchronization is gone.

How can I do that all the 4 `VideoView`s will be allways at the same second, that if one of them getting delayed, all the others wait for him so they could be Synchronization?

I am using local video files, but I will be glad to get answers for videos from the Internet too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to load video over internet or local video?

Comment: @Ramstein Local video, I have them all in R.raw directory